# Updating BIOS File Build Date

Tags: cpu, bios

I am in the process of updating my laptop's BIOS to add support for a CPU however I ran into an issue when I tried to adjust the build date of the BIOS file. After adjusting the file from built in 2011 to 2012, just so it recognizes as new BIOS, MMTool says it is invalid. PLEASE HELP!

Comment: There's most likely a checksum for your protection.  I strongly suggest you either locate an official release that solves your problem or forget about it or you'll likely end up bricking your BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help but after many hours of searching I finally found what i was looking for and it did solve this. Instead of having to patch the BIOS's build date I had to disable Asus's date check in WinFlash with then correctly flashed the new BIOS. Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

## ***Background and Follow up (skip):***

Totally 7 years late here.

I have a feeling this tends to happen with BIOS for ASUS products before ASUS EZ flash 2 Utility and ASUS EZ Flash 3 Utility. So, I'll keep this hear for the search engine.

## *Solution*

**Introduction:**
I'm back. So, now, being from the future, Google searches and Bing searches are super efficient. Found a few solutions. Seems to be that you use ASuSTek (ASUS) **WinFlash** on your OS instead of your ASUS EZ Flash 1/2/3/X BIOS app in the BIOS.

**NOTE:** If the procedure is too complicated for you, its likely that you shouldn't tinker with your BIOS as there is a risk you may BRICK your computer.

**DISCLAIMER:** If you do this, the risk is on you as you may brick your computer. Do at your own risk/peril.

Now, if you want to venture into this world and learn, [BIOSMODSFORUM](https://www.bios-mods.com/forum/Forum-Bios-Mods-Forum) is a great resource for specifics.

That said, Let's move on to the procedure.

Please see procedure below.

**Step 1:** Get, install, and use WinFlash

Here's a link to a video on YouTube explaining how use WinFlash:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XvW5g8Q-ZLs

And, here's a link to the ROG Forum touching on the same topic (WinFlash):

- https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/rog-gaming-notebooks/how-do-you-downgrade-bios-on-g55vw/td-p/238050

**Step 2:** If that does not work, download a BIOS metadata editor (Longsoft FD44 Editor, Open Source on [GitHub](https://github.com/LongSoft/FD44Editor/releases))

Here you will extract a bin file from any capsule file you may have. Then, use FD44 Editor to change the BIOS date. If this works, it should be able to flash via EZ Flash utility in the BIOS environment or WinFlash on your OS environment.

Hope this helps those using legacy devices.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).